# QString Copying

Tags: c++, qt

This question is probably very basic but today i came across an error saying

**"error: passing 'const QChar' as 'this' argument of 'QChar& QChar::operator=(const QChar&)' discards qualifiers"**

*"I don't know how does this assigment disqualifies string to string copying predefined by Qt ide".*

when i was copying required data from one string to another string using the following code

```
for(int i=reqposition;;i++)
{
    if(data.at(i)==',')
        break;

    temp.at(j)=data.at(i);  // ERROR IS HERE
    j++;
}
```

what is the problem in this code. Is there any other efficient way of copying data from one string from specified index to another string.
How do i solve this problem.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

```
const QChar QString::at(int position);
```

The problem is you're not assigning to the string; you're assigning to the `const QChar` result of the `QString::at(int)` call.

You want a modifiable reference instead: From the [QString documentation:](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#operator-5b-5d)

> QCharRef QString::operator[] ( int position ) Returns the character at
>   the specified position in the string as a modifiable reference.
>   Example:  QString str;
>
> if (str[0] == QChar('?'))
>        str[0] = QChar('_'); The return value is of type QCharRef, a helper class for QString. When you get an object of type QCharRef, you
>   can use it as if it were a QChar &. If you assign to it, the
>   assignment will apply to the character in the QString from which you
>   got the reference.

Comment: ok the program compiled fine when did
    for(int i=reqposition;;i++)
    {
        if(data.at(i)==',')
            break;

        temp[j]=data.at(i);  
        j++;
    }
However when i did
temp[j]=data[j];
i still got an error. Why is that. can you please tell me

Comment: what compiler are you using? both `temp[j]=data.at(i)` and `temp[j]=data[i]` work with no errors for me.

Answer (score 1):

QString::at returns a `const QChar`.

Use `temp[j]=data.at(i);`

Comment: what difference temp.[j] will make! I think this syntax temp.[j] is also wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, now fixed.  operator[] returns a reference to the QString's internal data, which allows you to assign to it.

Comment: what is the difference between temp[i]=data[i] and temp[i]=data.at(i);
because i got an error for temp[i]=data[i];
Note: both temp and data are QString objects

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for the `mid` method from QString [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#mid):

> Returns a string that contains n characters of this string, starting at the specified position index.

Answer (score 0):

Are this a snippet from a split code?
In this case isn't better use the QString.split function?

Comment: i am not spliting the string. Actually i am copying data from the string found through looping, from the specified index to another string object

Comment: In this case, is better obtain the indexes you need and use the mid function.

Almost like this

    int i = reqposition;

    for(;;i++)
    {
        if(data.at(i)==',')
            break;
    }

    QString tmp = data.midRef(reqposition, i);
    [/code]